Post Navigation based on ACF custom Field
I have a cpt for events and they are using ACF date field to order them on the archive page. The issue I'm having is that the post navigation orders them by post date and not the ACF date field. I'm looking for a function to change this behavior. I am using elementor page builder.
I found something similar from 2013 so I'm not sure if this is they way to go or not Link
Maybe a shortcode is the way to go for this but not completly sure how to go about it.
